# Is there any difference between fs.ReadStream and fs.createReadStream in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

In `fs` module in Node.js, is there any difference between `fs.ReadStream` and `fs.createReadStream`? As far as I know, both take filename and then create stream object...right?

Comment: Please post question 2 as a separate question.

Comment: `readFile` - It will read the file completely into memory before making it available to the User.                                                               `createReadStream` - It will read the file in chunks of the size which is specified before hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1124de2d76ad7118267d91a08485aa928a5f0865/lib/fs.js#L1711

```
fs.createReadStream = function(path, options) {
  return new ReadStream(path, options);
};
```

*Fine print: YES. fs.createReadStream costs you 1 extra wrapper function call*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is it essential to wrap the function? Which one should I use when I handle `ReadStream` usually? I don't get why this function has to be wrapped, especially since there are no other arguments taken as input and no line other than creating new instance inside the function.

Comment: I repeat, there is NO DIFFERENCE. You can use either one and it does not matter which. 'fs.createReadStream' is just a convenience method, perhaps for folks who don't like the `new` keyword.

Comment: Which code style should I prefer due on compatibility with `ES6`?